# Jest encountered an unexpected token SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a test for a react component, the component is a part of an application that uses FIrebase, Please see the test code.

```
/** @jest-environment jsdom */
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import WorkForm from '../../components/WorkFlow/WorkForm';






jest.mock('../../UI/PwFormButtons', () => ({
    PWSaveButton: () => <div data-testId="saveButton">Mocked PWSaveButton</div>,
}));

test("If work from render show save button", () => {
    
    const {getByTestId} = render(<WorkForm 
        isNew={true}
        workflowData={{}}
        setShowFlowContainer={() => {}}
        newWorkFlow={() => {}}
        user={{}}
        setShowModal={() => {}}
        updateWorkFlow={() => {}}
    />);
    expect(getByTestId("saveButton")).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

I keep getting a Firebase error, please see below.

```
    /Users/rayonhunte/Documents/GitHub/alert-manager/packages/config-ui/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { registerVersion } from '@firebase/app';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
        | ^
      2 | import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
      3 | import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
      4 | import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
```

I was also getting that error with react form hooks but after the lib update, it was resolved, that's not working with Firebase.

I am using react testing lib and Jest for testing and this is a NextJS and TypeScript application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jest config file

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.next/', '<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
};
```

babel file

```
{
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "presets": [
                "next/babel"
            ]
        },
        "production": {
            "presets": [
                "next/babel"
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "presets": [
                "@babel/env",
                "@babel/react",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
                    {
                        "allowTopLevelThis": true
                    }
                ]
                ]
        }
    }
}
```